# How encrypt list data to SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have problem encrypt my data in SharedPreference this is my current SharedPreference with save data not encrypt. I don't know what encrypt data.

```
 public class MySharedPreference {

//this is name PREFS_NAME
        public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LIST_CARD";
//this is CARD where are save data Card 
        public static final String CARD = "CARD";

        public MySharedPreference() {
            super();
        }

//this is functon witch save array list to Sharepreference 

    public void saveCardToSharedPreference(Context context, ArrayList<Card> cardList) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(cardList);
        editor.putString(CARD, jsonString);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you know about encryption, you can write it by urself, it just a processing encrypt data by many kinds of two-way encryption algorithm/hash such as SHA, AES or something else. If no, you can search "secured SharedPreference" many library or support class was there.

Answer (score 0):

following will help you

```
static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public static ArrayList<Card> getListSharedPref(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String json=sharedPref.getString("LIST_PREF",null);
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<Card>>(){}.getType();

    ArrayList<Card> beans = null ;
    try {
        beans = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null ;
    }
    return beans;
}

public static void setListSharedPref(Context context, ArrayList<Card> cardList) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(cardList);
    editor.putString("LIST_PREF",json);
    editor.commit();

}
```